# C# MVC Structuring a project with SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm a .net virgin but have been assigned a project using C# abd ASP.NET MVC (using visual studio express 2013 for web). I need the project to integrate with the client's SQL Server database.

They have stored procedures set up in the database to get and set data which does everything I need, but am unable to find much in the way of information on how I should be structuring my project.

If I was to bypass the stored procedures, I could just create a class for each of the tables but am struggling to get my head around how I should be structuring the project to use the stored procedures.

My first thought is that I no longer need models as the stored procedures effectively negate them. Am I correct in my thinking? If I bypass models entirely, how then do I handle things like view models?

For instance I can call a stored procedure like so from my controller:

```
var vehi_Models = db.spVehicleGetModels(ID_make, false, true, ID_country);
```

But in cases where I also need other data to send to the view ie:

```
var vehi_Models = db.spVehicleGetModels(ID_make, false, true, ID_country); 
var countries = db.spGetCountries();
```

Without viewmodels, I am unable to send all the data to the view.

Any thoughts or links to any training material I could use would be greatly appreciated. There isn't a wealth of information out there that I can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at EntityFramework. Although it can directly alter tables you can also edit the function mappings for insert/delete/update to use stored procedures.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc